# How to access object from within listener function in JS

Tags: javascript

I want to access **foo.settings.debug** object from inside the **success** listener of the **require()** function.  I keep getting an undefined error and when I reference "this" it ends up referencing the ajax object.  Please assist.

```
var foo = {

    info: {

        version: '0.0.1'

    },

    settings: {

        debug: true

    },

    require: function(script) {

        $.ajax({
            url: script,
            dataType: "script",
            async: false,
            success: function(){
                if(foo.settings.debug) console.log('loaded js file: ' + script);
            },
            error: function(){
                throw new Error("Could not load script " + script);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a reference to foo which is `this` inside of foo however `this` is going to be something else inside of your closure so you need to keep a reference to `this` like so:

```
require: function(script) {
        var self = this;
        $.ajax({
            url: script,
            dataType: "script",
            async: false,
            success: function(){
                if(self.settings.debug) console.log('loaded js file: ' + script);
            },
            error: function(){
                throw new Error("Could not load script " + script);
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: brain fart - I was doing that but at the level above that inside the foo declaration.  thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Every function has its own `this` object context. The context can be changed by using `apply` or other such functions.

In this case by creating an anonymous function as a callback for success you are entering a new context. In order to access the previous context you need to define a variable inside the previous context (with a name that will not be overridden by argument names of the callback function).

```
var foo = {

    info: {

        version: '0.0.1'

    },

    settings: {

        debug: true

    },

    require: function(script) {
        /* every function has its own 'this' context */
        var self = this;

        $.ajax({
            url: script,
            dataType: "script",
            async: false,
            success: function(){
                if(self.settings.debug) console.log('loaded js file: ' + script);
            },
            error: function(){
                throw new Error("Could not load script " + script);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Tiny bug: `self.settings.debug` not `self.debug`

Comment: Yes indeed, I initially wrote `self.settings.debug` but thought that `require` is defined in `foo.settings.require` meaning that it would be attached to `foo.require`. My mistake, `require` is defined in `foo.require` and attached to `foo`.